# Prepare failure: out of memory sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

So I get this error: Prepare failure 'out of memory.' Does anyone know why this would be? Note I tested my sql statement. It works great. Also, I am checking to open the database inside another method. It opens just fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
+(NSArray *) fetchListForFirstLEvelCategory
{


    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString * query;

        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select mobile_menu.title from sup_pick join sup_mast as mobile_menu on mobile_menu.custom_link1 = sup_pick.key_id and mobile_menu.show_id = '1D2EA159-A312-4FB5-8FE5-B95879B242BB' and mobile_menu.type = 996 and mobile_menu.active = 1 and mobile_menu.status = 1 where sup_pick.client_id = '2517EFF6-8063-4454-BA5F-23679F51AD5A' and sup_pick.active = 1 and sup_pick.parent_key = 'CB18E277-23E9-4232-A20C-AD4D051C578B' and sup_pick.field_name like '%%0000' Order by sup_pick.field_name,mobile_menu.display_order"];


        const char *query_stmt = [query UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt * sql;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &sql, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while (sqlite3_step(sql)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {


                    NSString* test= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];

                    [array addObject:test];



            }

            return array;


        }
    NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));

        return nil;

}
+(NSArray *) fetchListForFirstLEvelCategory
{


    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString * query;

        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select mobile_menu.title from sup_pick join sup_mast as mobile_menu on mobile_menu.custom_link1 = sup_pick.key_id and mobile_menu.show_id = '1D2EA159-A312-4FB5-8FE5-B95879B242BB' and mobile_menu.type = 996 and mobile_menu.active = 1 and mobile_menu.status = 1 where sup_pick.client_id = '2517EFF6-8063-4454-BA5F-23679F51AD5A' and sup_pick.active = 1 and sup_pick.parent_key = 'CB18E277-23E9-4232-A20C-AD4D051C578B' and sup_pick.field_name like '%%0000' Order by sup_pick.field_name,mobile_menu.display_order"];


        const char *query_stmt = [query UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt * sql;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &sql, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while (sqlite3_step(sql)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {


                    NSString* test= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];

                    [array addObject:test];



            }

            return array;


        }
    NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));

        return nil;

}
```

Comment: This usually indicates that you're not closing prepared statements, etc, when you should.  (Since I don't offhand see a call to sqlite3_finalize in your code I suspect this is your problem.)

Comment: Hint:  The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) is not the world's greatest, but it's pretty good.  It's always best to review the corresponding sections before you use a function you're unfamiliar with.

Comment: You will get an "Out of memory" error if the database reference is `nil`.